# Nginx As Frontend Proxy: Won't Pass Correct Hostname

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, hostname

```
server {
    listen x.x.x.X:80;
    server_name www.x.net;
    return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;

}

 server {

    listen x.x.x.x:443 ssl http2;
    server_name x.net www.x.net;
    root /home/x/public_html;

   location / {
        proxy_pass https://x.x.x.x:4343;
        add_header Cache-Control "public, must-revalidate, proxy-revalidate";
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
        include microcache.inc;
        include proxy.inc;

 }
  }
```

This is a simple setup that works flawlessly on another server. I am in the process of a migration and this does not work any longer with nginx 1.10+

My problem: **In the source code of the website it displays the actual IP rather than the hostname.** Why is nginx doing that? I have modified httpd.conf of apache to pass 4343 requests to nginx. Nginx should have no problem serving the website and it doesn't but *it's not showing the hostname properly, instead uses the host-IP.*

Any input much appreciated, what is the most likely issue? Standard proxy.inc..

```
proxy_redirect     off;
proxy_set_header   Host   $host;
proxy_set_header   Cookie $http_cookie;
proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
```

Comment: Are those the only `server {}` blocks in nginx ?

Comment: What is the actual request flow when the page is loaded? There you can see if nginx sends any redirects, which would change the URL in browser bar.